# spring mvc hibernate-validator not working

Tags: validation, spring-boot

pom.xml likes this.in spring-boot-starter-web,it already has hibernate-validator dependency.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.14.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ClassRequest

```
@Data
public class ClassRequest {

    String glade;

    Integer number;

    List<StudentRequest> students;
}
```

StudentRequest

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


@Data
public class StudentRequest {

    String name;
    Integer age;

    @NotNull(message="id not blank")
    String identity;

}
```

controller

```
@RestController
public class StudentController {
    @PostMapping("/class/info/create")
    public @ResponseBody Response createClassInfo(@RequestBody @Valid 
ClassRequest classRequest) {
        System.out.println(classRequest.getNumber());
        return Response.ok;
    }

}
```

Do I miss something?the validation not working.
I am learner. can some one help me?

Comment: Didn't you ask a similar question some time back?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482088/spring-boot-starter-web-hibernate-validator-dependency-missing-on-mac

Comment: i add  hibernate-validator dependency,it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

it is Nesting.it can validate classRequest. it can not validate studentRequest.just add @valid.

```
@Data
public class ClassRequest {

    String glade;


    Integer number;

    @valid
    List<StudentRequest> students;
}
```